# *** TypeError: __new__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'device_type' and 'device_id' error when executing deepcopy on overfit_batches

Tags: pytorch, deep-copy, pytorch-lightning, deviceid

When using `overfit_batches` functionality of PyTorch I see the following file `python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/data_loading.py` execute

```py
dataloaders = [deepcopy(train_dataloader) for _ in range(num_loaders)]
```

And that is resulting in the error:

```
TypeError: __new__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'device_type' and 'device_id'
```

Could someone please help?

The `deepcopy` and hence the `overfit_batches` should work fine.